# How to run a class before maven build?

Tags: java, maven

WHy does the following result in a build failure?
I created a class that should run *before* maven is starting to execute the build.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my.package.CustomClass</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Results in a build failure:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.CustomClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:281)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If you are running from a clean build, you won't have a compiled version of that class, so it can't be run. Perhaps if you said a bit more as to why you want to do this, we can figure something else out.

Comment: How could a main class be executed before it is even compiled? Maybe you want to bind the execution to the `process-classes` phase?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I need a `public static void main` class to run before `generate-sources` to initialize some properties for webservice authentication of an external wsdl service.

Comment: @membersound Then this class should be part of another project which builds its own artifact. This dependency should then be listed in the dependency's section of the plugin configuration.

Comment: So it's impossible to include that class in the project that only requires it??

Comment: You were right: if I copy the class to another lib and import it as dependency, the configuration works. But I'd still like to include the class just in the project that compiles.

Comment: @membersound then add it as another dependent maven (sub/parent)module

Comment: It sounds like your class is basically a short script. You could take a look at [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) which is a Groovy-based build tool that is pretty much Maven spin-off. It provides native support for running short groovy scripts as part of the build.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the phase(like 'test' or 'install') where the maven executes, so when plugin run the class it will be available in classpath.(in case if you really cannot move that to another dependency)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my.package.CustomClass</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: OP explained that he needs the execution in the "generate-sources" phase. Additionally, a better suited phase would be "process-classes".